# Docker Redis container getting WARNING: /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn in a user defined network

Tags: docker, redis

Hey guys I'm having a really hard time with this one and I need help. I need to run a Redis container on a user defined network and assign it a static ip so I have this:
`docker run -v /root/test/:/data/ -p 7001:7001 --net iso_nw --ip 172.18.0.2 --name testy -d redis redis-server /data/redis.conf`
This causes my Redis instance to display the TCP backlog warning:

`WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 65536 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.`

My brain is fried trying to make this warning go away without using `--net host`. Can someone help me please. Thanks.

Comment: please add the warning.

Comment: @JohnK edited the question to include the warning. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5):

You can use docker-compose to do this

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis
    command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes"]
    sysctls:
      - net.core.somaxconn=65535
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /data/redis:/data
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    restart: always

volumes:
  redis-data:
    driver: local
```

then run `docker-compose up -d`

Answer (score 3):

Latest version of docker now has --sysctl command available so this should do it:

```
docker run --name myredis --sysctl net.core.somaxconn=511 -d redis
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Ok first the TCP backlog setting that I'm trying to use is invalid. The max allowed value is 65535 which is a short unsigned int, so I updated my Redis config with this value.

Now I can run the container by loading /proc/ as a writable volume and echo the value:

```
docker run -v /root/test/:/data/ -v /proc/:/wproc/ -p 7001:7001 --net iso_nw --ip 172.18.0.2 --name testy -d redis echo 65535 > /wproc/sys/net/core/somaxconn && redis-server /data/redis.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, your command didn't work for me.
Instead, the following did:

```
docker run --name redis --rm -p 6379:6379 -ti --privileged redis:4.0.1 \
  /bin/bash -c 'echo 65535 > /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn ; redis-server'
```

These were the relevant findings:

- The nested commands (which are passed to bash) have to be quoted.
- Without `--privileged`, I couldn't write to `/proc/sys` of the container.

*Don't forget to use your own settings for ports, names, versions, ...*